# Issue while finding right string using xpath

Tags: xpath

My xpath is returning either

`John Hernandez | 12 Jul 2012`  or `13 July 2012` as string.

If string contains character `|` then I want string after `|` otherwise I want the whole string as it is.

I used following xpath :

```
 substring-after(string(./div/span[2]),'|')
```

Its giving me correct output 12 Jul 2012 if string contains | but if my string does not contains | its returning null. Is there any way to check if string contains | then use string after | o.w return whole string.

Can anyone help me to do this.

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 1.0 you can use

```
substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(./div/span[2]), "|", string(./div/span[2]), "|"), "|"), "|")
```

This  first normalizes  the strings to `John Hernandez | 12 Jul 2012 | John Hernandez | 12 Jul 2012 |` or respectively `13 July 2012 | 13 July 2012  |` and then always returns the second value in the |-list

(but you should switch to XPath 2 anyways, it is much nicer...)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XPath 2.0 then this will do:

```
if (contains(string(div/span[2]), '|')) 
then substring-after(string(div/span[2]),'|') 
else string(div/span[2])
```

If you're using XPath 1.0, then you must check the string in XSLT (or whatever you're using) before calling substring-after(). For example:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(div/span[2], '|')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(string(div/span[2]),'|')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="div/span[2]"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: is it possible within single xpath? .I am using xpath 1.0.

Comment: No. If you are using XPath 1.0 you must check the string in your code before calling substring-after().